# Mazda CX7 metallic pulsating sound when driving below 20 MPH

Tags: brakes, noise, mazda, driving

I have this issue with my CX7, when I drive at a regular speed, the car performs very well. Now when I release the gas pedal and brake the car makes no sound until it goes below 20 MPH, then I can hear a metallic pulsating sound coming from the front left side (driver side). I changed the sway bar links and the tie rod ends. I checked the brakes and they seem perfect (shoes are not worn).

***Any ideas of what this might be?***

Just in case it's not the timing chain, I already changed it.

Comment: Just because the pads are thick doesn't mean it's not the brakes.  Something as simple as a broken or missing retaining clip can cause noise like this.  Also, have you thought about the wheel bearing?

Comment: I checked the retaining clips, and they are all there, I clean them and re-install them. As for bearing don't you think it will be more like a low tire sound, not metallic clicking.

Comment: Sounds like you did a good check tho.  From the question I couldn't tell if you _really_ looked at the brakes or just peeked at them with a flashlight.  As far as the bearings, sound is very subjective, so I threw out a possibility.  If you've heard a bad bearing and really don't think that's it, then that's just adding more information to the post which is great.

Comment: I believe the clicking sound does not come from the wheel but from behind the pedals, it will stop as soon as a press the brake and resume when released

Comment: Does this sound vary with the tire rotation speed,or any change in pitch to the sound at all? Is it fixed in terms of loudness and car speed(below 20mph)?

Comment: I assume you've had the wheel off and you've rotated the hub manually so you can listen closely? And you could use a stethoscope to rule out individual parts.